# Videocast throught WebRTC for Hololens 2 project

Tags: webrtc, windows-mixed-reality

I have an assignment to display, into a Hololens 2 (Unity Project), two video feeds (stereo camera) coming from a LattéPanda. For now, I successfully manage to do the demo from the Mixed-Reality WebRTC project locally, but I have some difficulties with the remote streaming.

The problem is how to make my application based on the Mixed-Reality C# Core 3.1 connect to my NodeDSS signaler since the demo uses a `NamedPipeSignaler` class that can't reach out to localhost? So I look up the classes they provided in the hope of getting the required method to implement, also with the interaction it needs to do with the `PeerConnection` object. It started to be a little complicated, so we look up other solutions.

One of the solutions we found was the OWT-Server (Open WebRTC Toolkit) which seems to give us already dockerize application to videocast on its own. However, the documentation doesn't specify much other than we need to link the docker image to an "application", which is not clear what it is supposed to do. We don't have any way to specify the STUN/TURN server, nor the signaler IP address for that matter.

So my goal at this point is very simple: just make one feed appear into my Unity project. The LattéPanda's only objective right now is to cast the video without caring much for any interaction (for now): it won't receive or even need to listen to any feed coming back ever, and for now, there is no need to interact with other tools. I've been searching for about 2 weeks now and my GoogleFu is not that good apparently. Is there any tool that could achieve this?

*A little disclaimer*: I do believe I still lack an understanding of the Signaling process. It seems that WebRTC does not enforce any standard in that regard. What I understand is the communication protocol (WebSocket, HTTP/2) is not standardized, only the messaging is (what message needs to be sent/handle).

**EDIT**

To be clear, the LattéPanda currently runs a console application written in C# Core 3.1. The reason is, like I said, that the LattéPanda should not display any of its feed to a monitor connected to it, nor received/handle any feed from outside. We can see it like a surveillance camera that outputs its feed through WebRTC and doesn't need to receive any feed.

Comment: Have you tried FMETP STREAM? which allows you to stream between any Unity platforms.

Comment: Interesting, unfortunately, I might not have been clear enough, the LattéPanda project is not a Unity one, it is a C# Core 3.1. The LattéPanda will stream into a project that is built using Unity. Both projects use the same Mixed-Reality WebRTC library from Microsoft. I will update my post to reflect this. Thanks for your response.